# Master hostname: salt not found. Retrying in 30 seconds

Tags: salt-stack

I am trying to install salt stack while running the command

python C:\Python27\Scripts\salt-minion -c C:\salt\minion -l debug i am getting error message like Master hostname: salt not found. Retrying in 30 seconds

I am attaching my error report please find it

```
C:\salt>python C:\Python27\Scripts\salt-minion -c C:\salt\minion -l debug
WARNING: 'C:\\salt\\minion' directory does not exist.
[DEBUG   ] Missing configuration file: C:\salt\minion\minion
[DEBUG   ] Guessing ID. The id can be explicitly in set c:\salt\conf\minion
[INFO    ] Found minion id from get_fqhostname(): HoroppaLabs
[ERROR   ] Could not cache minion ID: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\
salt\\conf\\minion_id'
[DEBUG   ] Configuration file path: c:\salt\conf\minion
[WARNING ] Failed to open log file, do you have permission to write to c:\salt\v
ar\log\salt\minion?
[INFO    ] Setting up the Salt Minion "HoroppaLabs"
[DEBUG   ] Created pidfile: c:\salt\var\run\salt-minion.pid
[WARNING ] You have a version of ZMQ less than ZMQ 3.2! There are known connecti
on keep-alive issues with ZMQ < 3.2 which may result in loss of contact with min
ions. Please upgrade your ZMQ!
[DEBUG   ] Missing configuration file: c:\salt\conf\minion
[ERROR   ] Unable to import Python wmi module, some core grains will be missing
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\salt\grains\core.py", line 50, in <module>

    import wmi
ImportError: No module named wmi
[CRITICAL] Failed to load grains defined in grain file core.hwaddr_interfaces in
 function <function hwaddr_interfaces at 0x00000000037AA048>, error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\salt\loader.py", line 1127, in gen_grains
    ret = fun()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\salt\grains\core.py", line 1180, in hwaddr
_interfaces
    ifaces = salt.utils.network.interfaces()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\salt\utils\network.py", line 449, in inter
faces
    return win_interfaces()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\salt\utils\network.py", line 402, in win_i
nterfaces
    with salt.utils.winapi.Com():
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'winapi'
[CRITICAL] Failed to load grains defined in grain file core.ip6 in function <fun
ction ip6 at 0x00000000037A5EB8>, error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\salt\loader.py", line 1127, in gen_grains
    ret = fun()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\salt\grains\core.py", line 1129, in ip6
    return {'ipv6': salt.utils.network.ip_addrs6(include_loopback=True)}
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\salt\utils\network.py", line 577, in ip_ad
drs6
    ifaces = interfaces()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\salt\utils\network.py", line 449, in inter
faces
    return win_interfaces()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\salt\utils\network.py", line 402, in win_i
nterfaces
    with salt.utils.winapi.Com():
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'winapi'
[CRITICAL] Failed to load grains defined in grain file core.ip4 in function <fun
ction ip4 at 0x00000000037A5DD8>, error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\salt\loader.py", line 1127, in gen_grains
    ret = fun()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\salt\grains\core.py", line 1102, in ip4
    return {'ipv4': salt.utils.network.ip_addrs(include_loopback=True)}
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\salt\utils\network.py", line 546, in ip_ad
drs
    ifaces = interfaces()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\salt\utils\network.py", line 449, in inter
faces
    return win_interfaces()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\salt\utils\network.py", line 402, in win_i
nterfaces
    with salt.utils.winapi.Com():
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'winapi'
[CRITICAL] Failed to load grains defined in grain file core.ip_interfaces in fun
ction <function ip_interfaces at 0x00000000037A5F98>, error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\salt\loader.py", line 1127, in gen_grains
    ret = fun()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\salt\grains\core.py", line 1159, in ip_int
erfaces
    ifaces = salt.utils.network.interfaces()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\salt\utils\network.py", line 449, in inter
faces
    return win_interfaces()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\salt\utils\network.py", line 402, in win_i
nterfaces
    with salt.utils.winapi.Com():
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'winapi'
[ERROR   ] This master address: 'salt' was previously resolvable but now fails t
o resolve! The previously resolved ip addr will continue to be used
[WARNING ] Master hostname: salt not found. Retrying in 30 seconds
```

Comment: You have quite a few problems including a missing wmi python module, an older version of zeromq, and for some reason, an inability to write to the log file. With regards to the error you mentioned, by default salt-minion looks for the dns entry which matches salt for the salt-master. In this case, it doesn't look like there is an entry for salt in your domain and so it cannot contact the salt-master. You can change the salt master's location by changing it in the salt-minion config file on windows.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the Salt Windows installer found here?  http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/installation/windows.html

Once you've installed the Salt minion you can start up the minion in a terminal with elevated privileges like this:

`c:\salt\salt-minion.exe -l debug -c c:\salt\conf`

You'll want to modify  `c:\salt\conf\minion`  and set the "master" option to be the IP or hostname of your master.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,i tried to execute the command you suggested c:\salt\salt-minion.exe -l debug -c c:\salt\conf but i am getting like[WARNING ] SaltReqTimeoutError: Waited 60 seconds
[INFO    ] Waiting for minion key to be accepted by the master.
[DEBUG   ] Loaded minion key: c:\salt\conf\pki\minion\minion.pem

Comment: i given master=localhost